# Show that the coefficients satisfy the following condition

Tags: solution-verification, quantum-mechanics

Hi I was asked for my QM homework to show that coefficients $c_n$ in superposition

$$
\psi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\psi_n(x)
$$

Satisfy the following condition

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert(c_n)\rvert^2 = 1
$$

Use
$$
\int_0^L\lvert\psi(x)\rvert^2dx=1
$$

Can anyone please point me into good direction I tried to substitute $\psi(x)$ for the given sum but I am stuck in a loop.
Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- $\langle \psi, \psi \rangle = 1$
- $\langle \psi_m, \psi_n \rangle = \delta_{mn}$

Thus,
$$
1
= \langle \psi, \psi \rangle
= \langle \sum_m c_m \psi_m, \sum_n c_n \psi_n \rangle
= \sum_m \sum_n c_m^* c_n \langle \psi_m, \psi_n \rangle
= \sum_m \sum_n c_m^* c_n \delta_{mn}
= \sum_m c_m^* c_m
= \sum_m |c_m|^2
.
$$